# ListView as windows explorer

Tags: c#, listview, windows-explorer

do you know any good example how to create listView which will look and has the same methods as windows explorer.

copying, pasting, display thumbnails ??

I must use listView because I can't allow user to change directory, and I can't disable this option in windows explorer(I mean the place where can I click to go up or down or put path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been recommending [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/FileBrowser.aspx), never heard a complaint about it.  Note that an embeddable browser is available since Vista, it is wrapped by the ExplorerBrowser class available in the [Windows API Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack).

Beware that these kind of solutions put a lot of dependencies into your project.  Consider weighing that cost against simply implementing the OpenFileDialog's [FileOk event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.fileok.aspx) and canceling the OK button click if you don't like the path.

Answer (score 1):

It's no trivial task, but you can have a look at [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/ExpCombo.aspx). It's in VB.Net but it might serve as a source of inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote something, but I don't know how to add event on click on icon to get path of this icon.

```
    path = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;


ImageList imageList1 = new ImageList();
imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(256, 256);
imageList1.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth24Bit;
string[] iconFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg");

foreach (string iconFile in iconFiles)
{
   try
   {
      imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(iconFile));
   }
   catch
   {
         MessageBox("Error","");
   }
}

this.listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
this.listView1.LargeImageList = imageList1;

for (int j = 0; j < imageList1.Images.Count; j++)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();

    item.ImageIndex = j;   
    this.listView1.Items.Add(item);               
}
```

How to rebuild this code ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use Graphics.DrawImage to load the jog file and create a thumbnail out of it. This will only work for image files.

To get thumbnails of other file types, you must use the shell IExtractIcon interface.

For copying/pasting, use the DataFormats.FileDrop format with full paths of the files.

---

For a ready-made alternative, see our [FileView](http://www.ssware.com/megapack.htm) control.